# Is is necessary to map the memory allocated to the device by the OS to a virtual memory space?

Tags: memory, virtual, device, drivers

example while writing a driver we do the following

```
res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
```

We get the info about the memory allocated to the device.

So is it necessary that I use this memory using virtual address

```
virt_base = ioremap(res->start, resource_size(res));
```

*Can't we use the physical address itself to address the memory?*

If we can, so are there any specific advantages of using virtual memory or this is how kernel wants us to do...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely necessary. (On x86) Once paging is enabled in the CPU, *all* addresses visible to the OS (so you, the driver developer) are virtual addresses.  In other words, any address you read from or write to will be interpreted by the CPU as a virtual address. It will then go through the page table hierarchy to finally arrive at a physical address to put on the bus.

You can't use physical addresses - they will not be mapped, or mapped to something other than what you want.  This is why `ioremap` must exist and be used.